# SQLalchemy - Iterate through all mapped tables

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

I am currently creating a web app in Flask and use SQL-alchemy (not the flask version) to deal with reading and writing to my MySQL database.

I have about 15 different tables each mapped to a different declarative class, however the application is still in beta stages and so this number will probably increase.

I would like a way to iterate through every single table and run the same command on every single one. This is part of an update function where an admin can change the name of a book, this name change should be reflected in all the other tables where that book is referred to.

Is there a way to iterate through all your SqlAlchemy tables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want to achieve here, but if you use declarative base, you can try something like this:

```
tables = Base.__subclasses__()
for t in tables:
    rows = Session.query(t).all()
    for r in rows:
        ... do something ...
```

This gets all tables by listing subclasses of Base. Then it queries everything from each table in turn and loops through selected rows.

However, I do not quite understand why you would want to do this. How you describe your question is that you should have a Book table, and all others link to it if they want to reference books. This would be the relational model instead of dragging information on Books in each and every table and trying to manage them like this manually.

Comment: Perfect - Exactly what I was looking for, didn't know there was an in-built method for getting all the subclasses of a Base class. Thanks for your help!

Comment: SQLAlchemy declarative keeps a [registry of mapped classes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base.params.class_registry), and there's also `Base.metadata.tables`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä yes I tinkered with Base.metadata.tables before I asked the question but it seemed to only return a list of the actual table names, which were different form the class names. Thanks!

Comment: @Hannu - You would be correct! however you seem to over-estimate my intelligence. Although using a relational database is clearly the obvious way to go, at the start of my project I had no idea what a relational database was so this is how I laid out my architecture. Hopefully by the end of the project I will have enough time to correct these problems. Thanks!